# Merge two Gmail accounts or make one an alias of the other

Tags: gmail

How do I merge two Gmail accounts, or at least have one be an alias for another?

I have two Gmail accounts:

- email1@gmail.com
- email2@gmail.com

I would like some way to merge both of these accounts into one and have both emails be aliases for that one account.

My primary email account is the **email2@gmail.com** but I use other services with **email1@gmail.com**.  I'm OK with having the contents of one of those accounts destroyed.

How do I go about doing this merge?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use the following setup:

Under Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP, you can forward email from one account to another.

Under Accounts and Import, you can add additional email addresses using "send mail from another address." Select "Reply from the same address the message was sent to" to have Gmail pick the correct address automatically when you reply.

With this configuration, you will receive emails addressed to both accounts and can send from both accounts.

Answer (score 5):

I adopt the following technique:

1. Choose your **master gmail profile** and open **Gmail**
2. Select `Setttings > Accounts` and Import
3. Add **POP3 email account** and insert all info about secondary address
4. In the other account remember to allow **POP download** (`Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP`)

At this point all mail from the secondary account are loaded directly into your master account.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this can be done with Gmail.

You can however set up one to access the other via POP.

Answer (score 1):

You could also, Enable Multiple sign-in to either Gmail account.

Account Settings>Multiple Sign in

You can find more on this topic [Here](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=28776)