# Synchronise two Gmail accounts

Tags: email, imap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I merge 2 gmail accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/can-i-merge-2-gmail-accounts)

I've have two Gmail accounts and have been manually copying everything over from one account to the other. Is there an automatic way to do this? It's for backups.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward them. Go to the top right corner and click the gear in Gmail. Click mail settings, then go to the forwarding tab. You can add an account to forward all your incoming mail to. You can also setup a filter which will forward all emails with some certain attribute (from a certain person, containing a certain word or phrase, having a certain subject, etc.).

Comment: Thats what I was thinking but thought it was a little messy and time consuming - surely if you can simply drag and drop with thunderbird you can make this autonomous.

Comment: You can also drag and drop the labels onto individual emails. I'm not sure what, to you, is the most time consuming part of this. Please clarify, and maybe we can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Settings -> accounts](https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#settings/accounts) and configure the import from one mailbox to another.

Comment: Unfortunately not between two gmail accounts.